# What is the meaning of lam@ in ATS?

Tags: ats

Sometimes, I see code like the following:

```
var foo = lam@(x: int): int => ...
```

What is the meaning of `lam@`? What is the difference between `lam` and `lam@`?

Answer (score 2):

Memory-wise, `lam` creates a boxed closure (if it is a closure), and allocates it on the heap. `lam@` creates a flat closure, and allocates it on the stack frame.

See the [Chapter 26. Linear Closure-Functions](http://ats-lang.sourceforge.net/DOCUMENT/ATS2TUTORIAL/HTML/c1220.html)
 and [Chapter 27. Stack-Allocated Closure-Functions](http://ats-lang.sourceforge.net/DOCUMENT/ATS2TUTORIAL/HTML/c1267.html) in the official tutorial for reference.